# Remove toolbar button padding Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, padding, toolbar

I'm trying to fit more button into the toolbar by removing some extra padding on button but I didn't find any way to do that.

[image]

I'm trying to remove the padding in red.

I tried adding this to the manifest

```
<item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>
```

And this to styles.xml

```
<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>                  
</style>
```

But it didn't work. Is there any other solution?

Comment: I don't suggest you to reduce the padding as Google suggested in material design guidelines. You can use app:showAsAction="ifRoom" in menu for low priority items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In default Action bar you cannot reduce the padding. 
So you just create a custom toolbar for that and keep padding 0dp